# How to pass query parameters to next.js api handler when calling from inside of getStaticProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am under the impression that you can import api request handlers and call them directly inside of your getStaticProps function because of the documentation where it says:

> Note: You should not use fetch() to call an API route in your application. Instead, directly import the API route and call its function yourself. You may need to slightly refactor your code for this approach.

I have an api route at `/api/user/[id].js` and the implementation looks something like this:

```js
export default function user(req, res) {
  const userId = req.query.id;
  const user = getUserById(userId);
  res.json(user);
}
```

If I want to use this handler in the `getStaticProps` of another page in the front-end such as `/admin/user/[id].js` how would I pass the `id` query to the request handler? Calling it without any parameters doesn't work and throws an error saying that `req.query.id` is undefined.

```js
import userHandler from "../../api/user/[id].js";

export async getStaticProps(){
    // This is where the api handler is getting called
    const user = await userHandler();
    return { props: { user } }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest to do in order to make stuff work:

1. you do not need "dynamic" name for the file with your api calls handlers (instead of `/api/user/[id].js` you can create `/api/user.js`);
2. you need specify a page (file) for user details view. It should be created in `/pages/user/[id].js` and paste `getStaticProps` function there. Now once you change url in browser to `http://localhost:3000/user/whatever` `getStaticProps` will be called with ({ params: {id: 'whatever'}})

`getStaticProps` - gets `context` argument which consists of several properties. All the dynamic URL parts will be stored under `params` property, taking into account above part this should work:

```
export async getStaticProps({ params }){
    const user = await user(params.id);
    return { props: { user } }
}
```

If you need some additional explanation you are welcome to ask

Comment: I renamed the request handler from `user` to `userHandler` since I realized I reused the name `user` twice in my example. Yours seems like the way to go but I would just make the correction that you probably meant to write `await userHandler({ query: params })` because the handler is expecting a request object rather than the id itself. It answers the question but I don't know if this is future proof since it involves sending a fake request object without a lot of the values that are usually in the request object.

Comment: Seems like the correct way to call API handler is using `fetch` instead of importing handler directly, in such case the initial file name for the handler is correct:
`/pages/api/user/[id].js`. Now when you call `fetch` from `getStaticProps` you should seacify URL similar to folder structure of the handler:
`const user = await fetch('/api/user/whatever')`.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the API endpoint internally on the server. The `user()` handler in your API requires the `Request` and `Response` objects to be passed as arguments and there's no point in faking a HTTP request/response.

Instead, `export` the function your API uses to get the user data:
`getUserById(userId)`. Then, `import` and call it in `getStaticProps()`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too but I just wanted to do some more digging just to make sure there wasn't another alternative in case I had an API handler with a lot of logic. In those situations I would rather like to be able to reuse the logic from the handler than rewrite it in getStaticProps but I don't think it's doable without faking the req object.